# jQuery accordion section index

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I make this accordion generic? That is, instead of active:2 I want it to point to the next section(may be some function like next() or such...). Similarly, for previous section.

$('#accordion').accordion({collapsible: true, active:2});

Also once if it opens a section , is there a way to focus on the first or last input field of the section?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#selector").accordion({ 
    change : function(event, ui) {
        // Your code to expand the next section and/or select the first element
    }
    // There is also a changestart event you could use instead of change
});
```

Comment: Thanks Todd! But I basically need the code for expanding next section and focus on first element.

Comment: Why don't you try to figure it out yourself.  If you can't get it to work, tell me specifically what your problems are.  For starters, look at this (if you haven't already): http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change

Comment: Found out, its --> jQuery('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active');

Comment: Then can set active: jQuery('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active');